# Profiling memory usage in Play! Framework

Tags: playframework, akka

I have a Play! Framework application which I have been running in production for 3 years.
However, recently I had upgrade the version to 2.8 (from 2.5) and need to change some depreciated functions. In the process I started to use more Akka Actors.

However, now I am running out of memory over a period of time (2-5 days) which didn't happen before. As the upgrade was a big rewrite I cannot go back easily so am wondering if there is an easy to see why my memory usage is increasing all the time.When the memory is almost at the maximum the Akka webstreath stops responding (but no PermGen error yet).

I did add a 15min memory check and save the values and the graph below is the result, which clearly shows an incremental result.

[image]

I initially thought it was a problem with new Akka Actors created and not being released. While the amount of actors was increasing, after making some of them Singleton (there are no variables in them) that does not seem the case.

Is there a way to see what is taking this memory? I expect it is something that has a reference and as such the memory is not released, but it is hard to find if there is no clue.

[EDIT]
After running MAT is seems that akka.actor.ActorCell is retained with all the JSON data I send to the client. This is the procedure. Is there a reason the data is not released? Do I need to something with the Materializer or Source?

```
 private void sendDeviceData(List<Device> devices){
    ObjectNode response = Json.newObject();
    ObjectNode statusScreen = response.putObject("statusScreen");
    ArrayNode items = statusScreen.putArray("devices");         
    for(Device device : devices) {
        items.add(Json.parse(device.getStatusJson()));
    }
    Source<JsonNode, NotUsed> source = Source.single(response);
    source.to(hubSink).run(mat);
}
```

[EDIT 2]
Please find attached a screenshot of the dump. It seems that it is all nested for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Try gathering a heap dump with `jmap` (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture) and then analyze it in Eclipse MAT (https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) or any other memory profiler.

Comment: Great, that returned that "akka.actor.ActorCell" occupies 92% of the memory. It seems that all the data send through a WS to the webintrface are nested into each other. I updated my code.

Comment: How are you creating your actors?  One actor per request?  Note that actors are only stopped if they are explicitly stopped: just because there are no live `ActorRef`s pointing at the actor does not result in the actor being stopped and the state held by the `ActorCell` being reclaimed.  So if you're spawning an actor per request, it's on you to stop the actor after the request.

Comment: AbstractNodeQueue entries are most likely the mailbox of an actor, so it's no wonder that ActorCell shows up which is the actual actor implementation that owns that mailbox. It sounds as if there's an actor that doesn't process its mailbox (fast enough). I would look at the histogram in MAT and see which message types that might be.

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. In order to send the message back to the client I used 'source.to(hubSink).run(mat);'. When I changed that to 'hubSink.runWith(source,mat);' the obvious memory increase stopped. I will now need to do a long run with a memory dump to see if it actually did.